# Best way to read/analysis reoccurring data in a file

Tags: python, numpy, readlines

I want to know what is the best/easiest way to read and analysis reoccurring data from a file with python. E.g. file:

```
some text
some more text
x y z
23 23 45
45 67 89
23 64 67
some text
some more text
x y z
23 23 45
45 67 89
23 64 67
.
.
.
.
```

I want to read the xyz data and determine the change over the occurrences. I'm wondering if there is a better way then reading line by line and using an if statement to find and separate the numerical data. If the data was in different files I would loop over the file names and use np.loadtxt. For some reason I find it harder to deal with reoccurring data in a file then multiple files. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Given a flat file format like this, you have no reasonable option other than to consume it line by line. All you need to know is where a section of data is relevant - i.e., start and end delimiters.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is this true even if the format is known? E.g. 4 rows of text, xyz's repeat.

Comment: You can extract the parts that starts with `x y z` to the end and then give them to `np.fromfile` using an in-memory buffered file but you need the end of each section to be well defined. Note that `np.fromfile` should be fast only with the trunk version of Numpy. Alternatively you could try to use Pandas instead of this function.